# Scheduling notifications in Android

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I need to be able to schedule multiple Notifications at different times in the future.

I tried doing this with an AlarmManager, but that isn't suitable, for the following reason. From AlarmManager.set(): "If there is already an alarm for this Intent scheduled (with the equality of two intents being defined by filterEquals(Intent)), then it will be removed and replaced by this one."

Guess what, the sending intents *are* equal, apart from different Extra's (but those don't count for filterEquals).

**So how can I schedule multiple notifications**, which will still be shown when my application is killed (the whole reason I tried AlarmManager)?

Thanks.

Comment: Just as a note for future readers of this question: you can probably also make the `Intents` be different without disturbing your application logic. This is particularly true for component-based `Intent`s (e.g., `new Intent(this, MyClass.class);`). For those, the action and data are not part of the routing, so you can fill something in there to distinguish one from the next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Work out which event will occur first, schedule that, when your event fires have it schedule the next event to occur.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on the same problem and decided not to use AlarmManager. The scheduled notifications worked fine in a test environment but in reality the users got the first couple of notifications and then it just stopped as if the alarms were cancelled.

I decided to make use of a service that runs every 15min and sends notifications for things that are overdue. This way the process at least gets started again if something happens to it where as if the alarm gets cancelled for some reason, it does not get recreated.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use multiple notification means..use different requestCode for different time notification

```
     notificationManager.notify(request_code_1,notification);
     notificationManager.notify(requestCode_2,notification);
```